# Identity Server 4 - How to Define Supported Grant Types etc

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

In a current ASP.NET Core project  (`v2.1.6`) Identity Server 4 (`v2.2.0`) was implemented for user and API authentication and it works like a charm. The only `grant_type` that is set to the clients is `client-credentials` and the `scopes` are set to a few custom scopes where `offline_access` is *not* allowed.

After visiting the `.well-known/openid-configuration` it was found that more `grant_types` are supported than specified and `offline_access` is a supported scope even though it was disabled (shortened for brevity):

```
{
  "scopes_supported": [
    "custom_scope_1",
    "custom_scope_2",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "password"
  ],
}
```

The documentation of both [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io) but could not find a clue how to set such an option. I stumbled upon [an possibly older documentation](https://dbsphinxtest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/scopes.html) but this seems not to be part of the current version.

Is there any possibility to explicitly define the supported grant types during configuration which I just missed? Or is it generated automatically and cannot be set at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe those are all the ones that IdentityServer4 supports; i.e. its capabilities.

You can see how they are added [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/ResponseHandling/Default/DiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs) (line 223); the short answer is they are based on the *server* capabilities/configuration, and not individual Clients.

---

You configure each Client individually with the grant type(s) you want it to have enabled with the `ClientGrantTypes` collection.

If you're using the in-memory Client collection, these are called `AllowedGrantTypes` there.

---

Addition: as .well-known/openid-configuration is an open standards concept, not an IdentityServer one, you can see confirmation of the above [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html).

> grant_types_supported
>
> OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 Grant Type values **that this OP supports**.

Comment: Alright - so the document is generated based on what the server supports in total no matter what the actual clients support?! If the authentication is successful depends then on the actual setting for the client (which works as wanted).

Comment: I'll check the first part, but certainly the second part is true (although clearly you can only add Client grant types that fall within the server's capabilities).

Comment: Thanks a lot @sellotape! I understand now how it works. The grant types are as supported by the auth server / OP, in this case IDS4, and can be extended by custom grants if required - [see the docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#refextensiongrants).

Comment: Is it possible to restrict the grant types at the server level? If all clients are not using certain grant types, then it'd be helpful to disable it at server level.